# How to make error messages appear on side the text field instead of under of it using mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, validation

I am using mootools default form validator plugin for my project. I have created a "validation-advice" class in the css and display is given as "inline-block', but the error is getting displayed under the text field. I want it on the side of the text field. I have googled it, but no resource found on it. Can anybody help me on this ? Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The style seems to be specified inline using the plugin. So, your class definition is overwritten.

Comment: I have done something like this and it gave 50% result:   `code` new Form.Validator.Inline($('regForm'), {showError: function(element){ element.setStyles(display: 'inline-block');}}); `code`. It placed errors on the side of the text field, but on dissolving it went under it.

Comment: I think its Fx is causing the issue. It must be resetting the style to block. Could you put up your code.

Comment: I have done the work. It is as follows: `code`<input type="text" name="consumerNumber" id="consumerNumber" class="inputs tipz required msgPos:'errConsNo'" />`code`. Now you have to create a <div> or something with id as "errConsNo". Thank you very much man, for taking time and effort to read and reply my question.

Comment: Awesomeness! Mootools... Cryptic :)